# What's the importance of solving problems

Tags: soft-question, education

I've heard every one say that solving problems in physics is important. In fact every textbook has a problem set at the end of a chapter. Some students even buy problem sets!.

But then I wonder do great physicists also solve problems like common students like me, or do they choose any other strategy to explore concepts? What does solving problems do?

Comment: see https://www.sns.ias.edu/sites/default/files/files/ThreeCheersShutUp.pdf by Nima Arkani-Ahmed, one person who certainly explores concepts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solving problems is absolutely essential for both learning and doing physics. Physics is often very non-intuitive. Of course, topics like quantum mechanics and relativity are non-intuitive because they lie so far outside of everyday life, but even classical mechanics such as gyroscopes can be quite non-intuitive.

One of the primary benefits of doing practice problems is to build intuition. As you repetitively work through problems you can build intuition. Although you cannot experience a black hole or quantum entanglement, by repeatedly doing problems you can gain intuition for how they work.

Beyond building intuition, problems are also essential for experimentation. When we build an experiment we have to build both the experimental device and solve the equations describing the experiment. Without solving the problem we would have nothing to compare the measurements to.

Regarding great physicists, they all solved many problems to learn, just as anyone else did. As they advance to the edge of human knowledge they continue to solve problems. The only difference is that at a certain point they have to write their own problems, and the only way to know if they got the question and the answer right is through experiments.

Comment: Thank you I'm trying to solve as many as possible.